# How to get around this - "Error: You cannot reassign a recurring task occurrence."?

Tags: tasks

Any idea on how to get around this error:

> You cannot reassign a recurring task occurrence.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I read this from the documentation but I'm trying to figure out a work around as I'm assigned to transfer 2000 tasks and half of them are recurring so I'm not sure how I'll be moving them to the other owner, without going through a process of recreating 1000 recurring tasks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the IsRecurrence field you can know which is the main task that generated the recurrence.

If the strategy applies to your business just clone those tasks with a different owner.
Than delete all task which RecurrenceActivityId = taskYouAreClonning.
And Last delete the task you just clonned.

Comment: This is very helpful!

Answer (score 5):

Are you working from Apex of via the UI?

From Apex, have a read of [Task - Recurring Tasks](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_task.htm#RecurTasks). If the IsRecurrence field is true on the current Task you can use the RecurrenceActivityId to get the ID of the main record that created the current recurrence.
You can then modify this parent record.

From the UI, first use the edit series link in the recurrence to get to the parent record and modify that.

Comment: I'm using Force.com's excel connector and I'm also trying the UI for modifying tasks in Salesforce but stuck with this "Error: You cannot reassign a recurring task occurrence.". This IsRecurrence, I've seen, not sure what we can do with this, RecurrenceActivityId, though. Would the latter help with the reassignment of the task? Appreciate your suggestions on this.

Comment: Depending on the criteria you are using to select the Tasks to update, try only finding records that have IsRecurrence = false. In updating these you should automatically update the recurrences as well.

Comment: I can't, the tasks I'm trying to transfer are recurring, amounting to a thousand and figuring out how to accomplish without recreating one by one.

Comment: You shouldn't need to alter the recurring tasks. If you find and alter just the tasks identified by the RecurrenceActivityId (those tasks that create the recurrences) then the rest will follow automatically.

Comment: I can try to look for these RecurrenceActivityId, but I'm not sure if this would allow me to change the owner and get me past the "Error: You cannot reassign a recurring task occurrence." error.