# MIXED_DML_OPERATION on closing tasks upon user deactivation

Tags: apex, trigger, dml-operations

I created a trigger that queries and deletes all related tasks once a user in deactivated.

and I am getting this frustrating error.

> "MIXED_DML_OPERATION, DML operation on setup object is not permitted
>   after you have updated a non-setup object (or vice versa): Task,
>   original object: User: []: Trigger.AutoDeleteTasks4InactiveUsers: line
>   25, column 1"

here is my trigger:

```
trigger AutoDeleteTasks4InactiveUsers on User (after update) 
{

        Set<Id> UserIds = new Set<Id>();

        for (User u: trigger.new)
        {
            if(u.IsActive == false)
            {
                UserIds.add(u.id);
            }

        }    


        List<Task> Task2Close = [SELECT Id from Task 
                                  where IsClosed = false 
                                    and OwnerId = :UserIds];

        for(Task tsk : Task2Close)
        {
            tsk.Status = 'Closed - User Deactivated';
        }

        if(!Task2Close.isEmpty())
        {
            update Task2Close;
        }
}
```

can a good samaritan lend a helping hand.

I already tried using a class but still the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reason for Mix DML error

**[sObjects That Cannot Be Used Together in DML Operations DML](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_non_mix_sobjects.htm)**

> operations on certain sObjects sometimes referred to as setup
>   objects, can’t be mixed with DML on other sObjects in the same
>   transaction. This restriction exists because some sObjects affect the
>   user’s access to records in the org. You must insert or update these
>   types of sObjects in a different transaction to prevent operations
>   from happening with incorrect access-level permissions. For example,
>   you can’t update an account and a user role in a single transaction.
>   However, deleting a DML operation has no restrictions.

### Solution - Use Future method

you need to use future method for updating the task records. That will solve your mix DML error

```
if(!Task2Close.isEmpty())
{
     // call a future method. SInce we can pass list in future method thats why
    // pass the json string 
    futureClassForUpdate.updateTak(json.serialize(Task2Close));
}
```

### Future Method

```
public class futureClassForUpdate
{
    @future
    public static void updateTak(String strJSON)
    {
        // deserialize your string into list of task and update that list in future method to avoid mix dml error 
        List<Task > lstTask = (List<Task>) json.deserialize(strJSON, List<Task >.class);
        update lstTask;
    }
}
```

### Updates - Handler Recurrence Task Update

> INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, You cannot update the Status of a
>   recurring task.: [Status]"

I got this answer [How to get around this - “Error: You cannot reassign a recurring task occurrence.”?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/13066/18731)

> From Apex, have a read of Task - Recurring Tasks. If the IsRecurrence
>   field is true on the current Task you can use the RecurrenceActivityId
>   to get the ID of the main record that created the current recurrence.
>   You can then modify this parent record.
>
> From the UI, first use the edit series link in the recurrence to get
>   to the parent record and modify that.

To handle this error, you need to update recurrence task's parent task record

```
trigger AutoDeleteTasks4InactiveUsers on User (after update) 
{

        Set<Id> UserIds = new Set<Id>();

        for (User u: trigger.new)
        {
            if(u.IsActive == false)
            {
                UserIds.add(u.id);
            }
        }    
        List<Task> Task2Close = [SELECT Id, IsRecurrence, RecurrenceActivityId 
                                   FROM Task 
                                  where IsClosed = false 
                                    and OwnerId = :UserIds];
        // use new list of task to update the record 
        List<Task> lstTask = new List<Task>();
        for(Task tsk : Task2Close)
        {
            // if task is recurrence type then get the parent task Id using RecurrenceActivityId and update parent task status
            lstTask.add(new Task(Status = 'Closed - User Deactivated', 
                                Id = tsk.IsRecurrence ? tsk.RecurrenceActivityId : tsk.Id ));
        }

        if(!lstTask.isEmpty())
        {
            // call a future method. Since we can't pass list in future method thats why
            // pass the json string 
            futureClassForUpdate.updateTak(json.serialize(lstTask));
        }
}
```

Comment: I am gonna give it a try right away sir.

really appreciate the help.

Comment: apologies sir but I aint good with future methods but is this future method supposed to update the task status?

sorry for the dumb question

Comment: @JOE yes it will update task status. This way take 1-2 second more. also check debug logs if you got any exception or not

Comment: oh thanks a lot @ratan. let me check the logs and one more, if I may, will this close recurring tasks too?

Comment: I guess the debug log answered the question.
" INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, You cannot update the Status of a recurring task.: [Status]"

I guess I am dead?

Comment: @JOE check my updates.

Comment: I still have this on debug log

'You cannot update the Status of a recurring task.: [Status]'

sorry to take up so much of your time.

Comment: @JOE I am not sure how this is still giving the error. I guess ask a separate question regarding this error. Hope someone will solve your problem

Comment: I really appreciate the time and the big help @Ratan.

thank you for you patience.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44289/discussion-between-joe-and-ratan).